# How can you maintain a value (int or string) for use after closing an application

Tags: ios, string, int

I have some ints and strings that change as the app is played.  I would like to keep a revolving score that can be added to after the application closes and reopens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the program closes ( or at some checkpoint ) you can save the data to storage medium, e.g. file(s), registry key(s), database record(s).  Then when the program loads ( or possibly a dialog invoked by he user ) load said record(s).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest approach would be to use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

If it's something simple like it sounds, read up on [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000719-BAJFBAAH). Otherwise, if it's a little more complicated, like you want to have multiple users, etc., then read up on [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). Also, [AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat) is a decent Core Data example.